# Regex needs too long to fail, if there is no match

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I have the following regex string and the text string below. I have multiple nodes which I read into a string using `streamstreader`. After that I try to match using `regex.match()` to match the string, when there is a match its runs very fast even where there are numerous nodes. When there is not a match, the `regex.match()` method never stops.

My question when the string is not a match, I just want to catch an exception. For example in the data node below lets says some fields are totally missing and in that case I am ok to catch an exception, the problem is how to stop match routine if the node format is different?

```
string pat = @"TEST_REPLICATE\s*{\s*REPLICATE_ID\s*([^}]*?)\s+ASSAY_NUMBER\s*([^}]*?)\s+ASSAY_VERSION\s*([^}]*?)\s+DILUTION_ID\s*([^}]*?)\s+SAMPLE_ID\s*([^}]*?)\s+SAMPLE_TYPE\s*([^}]*?)\s+TEST_ORDER_DATE\s*([^}]*?)\s+TEST_ORDER_TIME\s*([^}]*?)\s+TEST_INITIATION_DATE\s*([^}]*?)\s+TEST_INITIATION_TIME\s*([^}]*?)\s+TEST_COMPLETION_DATE\s*([^}]*?)\s+TEST_COMPLETION_TIME\s*([^}]*?)\s+ASSAY_CALIBRATION_DATE\s*([^}]*?)\s+ASSAY_CALIBRATION_TIME\s*([^}]*?)\s+TRACK\s*([^}]*?)\s+PROCESSING_LANE\s*([^}]*?)\s+MODULE_SN\s*([^}]*?)\s+LOAD_LIST_NAME\s*([^}]*?)\s+OPERATOR_ID\s*([^}]*?)\s+DARK_SUBREADS\s*([^}]*?)\s+SIGNAL_SUBREADS\s*([^}]*?)\s+DARK_COUNT\s*([^}]*?)\s+SIGNAL_COUNT\s*([^}]*?)\s+CORRECTED_COUNT\s*([^}]*?)\s+STD_BAK\s*([^}]*?)\s+AVG_BAK\s*([^}]*?)\s+STD_FOR\s*([^}]*?)\s+AVG_FOR\s*([^}]*?)\s+SHAPE\s*([^}]*?)\s+EXCEPTION_STRING\s*([^}]*?)\s+RESULT\s*([^}]*?)\s+REPORTED_RESULT\s*([^}]*?)\s+REPORTED_RESULT_UNITS\s*([^}]*?)\s+REAGENT_MASTER_LOT\s*([^}]*?)\s+REAGENT_SERIAL_NUMBER\s*([^}]*?)\s+RESULT_FLAGS\s*([^}]*?)\s+RESULT_INTERPRETATION\s*([^}]*?)\s+DILUTION_PROTOCOL\s*([^}]*?)\s+RESULT_COMMENT\s*([^}]*?)\s+DATA_MANAGEMENT_FIELD_1\s*([^}]*?)\s+DATA_MANAGEMENT_FIELD_2\s*([^}]*?)\s+DATA_MANAGEMENT_FIELD_3\s*([^}]*?)\s+DATA_MANAGEMENT_FIELD_4\s*([^}]*?)\s*}";  



    TEST_REPLICATE
    {
        REPLICATE_ID            353
        ASSAY_NUMBER            34224
        ASSAY_VERSION           99
        ASSAY_STATUS            VALKID
        DILUTION_ID         1
        SAMPLE_ID           "NC_3e2e2"
        SAMPLE_TYPE         Specimen
        TEST_ORDER_DATE         05.21.2012
        TEST_ORDER_TIME         03:44:01
        TEST_INITIATION_DATE        05.21.2012
        TEST_INITIATION_TIME        04:03:36
        TEST_COMPLETION_DATE        05.21.2012
        TEST_COMPLETION_TIME        04:29:32
        ASSAY_CALIBRATION_DATE      NA
        ASSAY_CALIBRATION_TIME      NA
        TRACK           1
        PROCESSING_LANE     1
        MODULE_SN       "EP334545004"
        LOAD_LIST_NAME          C:\BSQ_SASDACC\ASDADAjson
        OPERATOR_ID         "Q_SI"
        DARK_SUBREADS           NA
        SIGNAL_SUBREADS         NA
        DARK_COUNT          NA
        SIGNAL_COUNT            NA
        CORRECTED_COUNT         NA
        STD_BAK             NA
        AVG_BAK             NA
        STD_FOR             NA
        AVG_FOR             NA
        SHAPE               NA
        EXCEPTION_STRING        Test execution was stopped.
        RESULT              NA
        REPORTED_RESULT         NA
        REPORTED_RESULT_UNITS       NA
        REAGENT_MASTER_LOT      ASDADA
        REAGENT_SERIAL_NUMBER       25022
        RESULT_FLAGS            NA
        RESULT_INTERPRETATION       NA
        DILUTION_PROTOCOL       ASDASD
        RESULT_COMMENT          ASDA ASDA1
        DATA_MANAGEMENT_FIELD_1     NA
        DATA_MANAGEMENT_FIELD_2     NA
        DATA_MANAGEMENT_FIELD_3     NA
        DATA_MANAGEMENT_FIELD_4     NA
    }
```

Comment: What is the code you are using to find a match?

Comment: I am using something like this `static Regex _regex = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);` and then `match m = _regex.match(text);`

Answer (score 0):

> You can determine whether the regular expression pattern has been found in the input string by checking the value of the returned Match object's Success property. If a match is successful, the returned Match object's Value property contains the substring from input that matches the regular expression pattern. If no match is found, its value is String.Empty.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z2heewz.aspx

When I test the following with your supplied values, Success returns true.  If I change your text to a format that doesn't match, it returns false as expected.

```
var found = Regex.Match(inputString, pat).Success
```

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

1. If you write such a regex, please use the option `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace`, it allows you to use whitespace in the regex to make it more readable. This whitespace is not matched! If you want to match a space, you have to escape it `\`, or use `\s` (what you are already doing).
2. You don't use a `.` in your pattern, so no need for `RegexOptions.Singleline`. This option is changing the behaviour of the special character `.`, if you don't use it, you don't need the option.
3. If your pattern fails, because some of the keywords are missing your regex has some possibilities to match using the `[^}]*?`, I would narrow it down to use `\S*` instead, `\S` is matching a non-whitespace character (would work for your example, I see no whitespace in the data you want to extract), so your regex should fail much faster.

   **Update:** My mistake, your example has whitespace at some point. Then I would replace the `\S*` with `.*?`. Since I didn't use the Singleline option, this would also not match the newlines and because I made it ungreedy it will not include the whitespace at the end of the rows.

   If you have the option to narrow the pattern down, this would be better. E.g. if you know a value can only be digits, then match only for `\d+`.

Try this pattern:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"TEST_REPLICATE\s*
                         {\s*
                         REPLICATE_ID\s*(\S*)\s+
                         ASSAY_NUMBER\s*(\S*)\s+
                         ASSAY_VERSION\s*(\S*)\s+
                         DILUTION_ID\s*(\S*)\s+
                         SAMPLE_ID\s*(\S*)\s+
                         SAMPLE_TYPE\s*(\S*)\s+
                         TEST_ORDER_DATE\s*(\S*)\s+
                         TEST_ORDER_TIME\s*(\S*)\s+
                         TEST_INITIATION_DATE\s*(\S*)\s+
                         TEST_INITIATION_TIME\s*(\S*)\s+
                         TEST_COMPLETION_DATE\s*(\S*)\s+
                         TEST_COMPLETION_TIME\s*(\S*)\s+
                         ASSAY_CALIBRATION_DATE\s*(\S*)\s+
                         ASSAY_CALIBRATION_TIME\s*(\S*)\s+
                         TRACK\s*(\S*)\s+
                         PROCESSING_LANE\s*(\S*)\s+
                         MODULE_SN\s*(\S*)\s+
                         LOAD_LIST_NAME\s*(\S*)\s+
                         OPERATOR_ID\s*(\S*)\s+
                         DARK_SUBREADS\s*(\S*)\s+
                         SIGNAL_SUBREADS\s*(\S*)\s+
                         DARK_COUNT\s*(\S*)\s+
                         SIGNAL_COUNT\s*(\S*)\s+
                         CORRECTED_COUNT\s*(\S*)\s+
                         STD_BAK\s*(\S*)\s+
                         AVG_BAK\s*(\S*)\s+
                         STD_FOR\s*(\S*)\s+
                         AVG_FOR\s*(\S*)\s+
                         SHAPE\s*(\S*)\s+
                         EXCEPTION_STRING\s*(\S*)\s+
                         RESULT\s*(\S*)\s+
                         REPORTED_RESULT\s*(\S*)\s+
                         REPORTED_RESULT_UNITS\s*(\S*)\s+
                         REAGENT_MASTER_LOT\s*(\S*)\s+
                         REAGENT_SERIAL_NUMBER\s*(\S*)\s+
                         RESULT_FLAGS\s*(\S*)\s+
                         RESULT_INTERPRETATION\s*(\S*)\s+
                         DILUTION_PROTOCOL\s*(\S*)\s+
                         RESULT_COMMENT\s*(\S*)\s+
                         DATA_MANAGEMENT_FIELD_1\s*(\S*)\s+
                         DATA_MANAGEMENT_FIELD_2\s*(\S*)\s+
                         DATA_MANAGEMENT_FIELD_3\s*(\S*)\s+
                         DATA_MANAGEMENT_FIELD_4\s*(\S*)\s*
                         }"
     , RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: In C# I find it easier to use `(?flags)` instead of the parameters, `(?xi)` in this case. Btw, some of those values have space, so `\S*` won't work in those cases.

Comment: @Qtax, my mistake, I haven't seen the values with spaces inside. For the inline options, I think its a matter of taste. If the option should be used on the whole pattern, I go for the normal, modifiers.

Comment: Well the test replicate node I have will sometimes have more fields and but the fields I want will always be there for instance ReplicateID, AssayNumber,  TEST_INITIATION_DATE, TEST_INITIATION_TIME,TEST_COMPLETION_DATE,TEST_COMPLETION_TIME\s, Exception_string and result. Is it possible if I could ignore everything else and get these fields?